# Loading properties file from resources directory (IDE vs runnable JAR)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

[image: maven folder structure]

Jar content:

[image: jarContent]

I have Maven project(Java 1.8) and problem when loading some resources file from  IDE and from runnable JAR. I tried this combinations:

```
1) CalendarSample.class.getResourceAsStream("/test/client_secrets.json")); //IDE
2) CalendarSample.class.getResourceAsStream("test/client_secrets.json"));
3) CalendarSample.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/test/client_secrets.json")); //JAR
4) CalendarSample.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/test/client_secrets.json"));
```

When running java program from inside IDE(eclipse mars) line 1 works

When running from standalone runnable jar ( win) line 3 works)

Using class loader:

```
5) CalendarSample.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/test/client_secrets.json")); 
6) CalendarSample.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test/client_secrets.json")); //IDE
7) CalendarSample.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/resources/test/client_secrets.json"));
8) CalendarSample.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/test/client_secrets.json")); //JAR
```

When using class loader running java program from inside IDE(eclipse mars) line 6 works

When running from standalone runnable jar ( win) line 8 works)

Am I missing something fundamental, what is preferred way to do this ? 
Is there combination that runs both in JAR && IDE?

Comment: looks like you have a problem in your `POM.xml` so that the `maven-resource-plugin`  includes the `resources` folder instead of copyimng its content only...

Answer (score 0):

Working on my side, can you check if your jar is containing a 'test' folder with your json in it? (open your jar with 7zip for example to see)